# Android: Align button to bottom-right of screen using FrameLayout?

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to put the zoom controls of the map on the bottom right corner of screen. I could do it with RelativeLayout using both `alignParentBottom="true"` and `alignParentRight="true"`, but with Framelayout I did not find any such attributes. How do I align it to the bottom-right of screen?

Comment: In Kotlin:  parameters.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Actually it's possible, despite what's being said in other answers. If you have a `FrameLayout`, and want to position a child item to the bottom, you can use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` and that is going to align that child to the bottom of the `FrameLayout`.

I know it works because I'm using it. I know is late, but it might come handy to others since this ranks in the top positions on google

Comment: Hi byte1918, if you consider this not to be the right answer for the question you're more than welcome - and I think it would be useful for everybody - if you post the right solution. Or explain at least what makes this a wrong answer. Thanks.

Comment: To align bottom right you can use android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"

Comment: if it does not immediately reflect in the preview, try setting it from the design tab. usually works,

Comment: I have tried that with Textview and it is not working

Answer (score 60):

I also ran into this situation and figured out how to do it using FrameLayout.
The following output is produced by the code given below.

[image: Some right-bottom aligned text showing up over an image using FrameLayout.]

```
              <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/contactbook_icon"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="140"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                        android:layout_margin="15dp" />
                </FrameLayout>
```

Change the margin value to adjust the text position over the image. Removing margin might make the text to go out of the view sometimes.

Comment: best answer ... thanks, solved a long standing mystery.

Answer (score 38):

It can be achieved using `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ImageView 
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is don't work, if use `wrap_content` in `RelativeLayout`. Because then anyway RelativeLayout scaled on whole screen.

Answer (score 17):

Setting `android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"` worked for me

Answer (score 11):

Two ways to do this:

1) Using a Frame Layout

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
```

2) Using a Relative Layout

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: why we use gravity, what is specific for

Answer (score 5):

If you want to try with java code. Here you go -

```
    final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM; // set gravity
```

Comment: just what I want. Little addition - LayoutParams should be from FrameLayout.LayoutParams. And if you want it bottom right corner use :  params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT;

Answer (score 4):

Use `bottom|right` as the `layout_gravity` value of the element which you wish to align in the bottom right position of the parent layout.

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add an invisible TextView to the FrameLayout.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/daily_delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="DELETE"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/daily_save_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SAVE"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to do this using constraint widget of the activity.xml page of android studio.

Two most common methods are:

1. Select your button view and adjust it's margins.
2. Go to "All attributes",then to "layout_constraints",then select

   - layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf_parent
   - layout_constraintRight_toRightOf_parent

Answer (score -3):

You can't do it with FrameLayout.

From spec:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

"FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. You can add multiple children to a FrameLayout, but all children are pegged to the top left of the screen."

Why not to use RelativeLayout?

Comment: I want a List to be shown on the left side, overlapping the map. Oh that is possible with RelativeLayout isnt it? Ok thanks.

Comment: "but all children are pegged to the top left of the screen" - not necessarily the top of the screen, you can align it to right, bottom etc right?

Comment: Yes, that is possible with RelativeLayout. You can layout views on top of each other.

Comment: This is actually half correct. What OP is asking is achievable but with limited view of-course as you mentioned. But saying that this is 'not achievable' would be wrong!